# Missing tool in the Toolbar (Shading/UVs)

Tags: modeling, interface

I'm trying to duplicate a tutorial about particles (making sprinkles).

However, there is a step wherein I have to invert the hair particle, using a button under the "Shading/UVs" tools.

This toolbar does not display in my Blender (I'm using 2.79b) so I'm stuck and I cannot seem to activate it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "*Shading/UV*" panel of the Tools shelf is available in *Edit Mode*  only.

Try hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to *Edit Mode*.

Comment: I don't have it in edit mode either